# Создать матрицу из набора чисел полученных из CSV файлa

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, numpy, csv

У меня есть CSV файл, где записаны числа. Мне нужно, из этих чисел сделать матрицу:

```
with open('nrw.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
for col in spamreader:
    cl0=float(col[0])
    cl1 = float(col[1])
    cl2 = float(col[2])
    print(cl0,cl1,cl2)
```

Результат:

```
3.069488981 2.070734076 3.875050524
2.901312467 1.985000133 3.751718667
2.687302 1.876456 3.595749
2.589985 1.818969 3.52211
2.458561 1.771084 3.450389
2.227072 1.640119 3.242741
2.007232 1.522668 3.055331
1.906016 1.480292 3.054023
```

И т.д., там 426 строк и 13 столбцов, это только часть.

Как мне теперь из этого сделать матрицу?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь специально предназначенной для этого функцией - [np.genfromtxt(...)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=';')
```

также можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas - результатом будем DataFrame, который можно легко преобразовать в матрицу:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=';')
arr = df.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

with open("Data.csv") as file_name:

    array = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=",")

print(array)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]